# Centos SSH & SFTP user restriction to specific directories

Tags: centos, ssh, permissions, security, restricted-shell

I am managing a server running Cantos 7. Some users login to the server via ssh/sftp for development. For them i have created a user `devel`. For security reasons, i need to confine them to certain directories. They should be able to:

- Run only basic commands such as `cd`, `ls`, `cp`, `cat`, `mv`, `mkdir`, `rmdir`, etc.
- Run programs such as `java`, `gcc`, `python` etc.
- Access home directory (`devel`) with full permissions (`rwx`)
- Access a mounted Hard Drive `/mnt/dataspace` with full permissions (`rwx`)
- Access the `/usr/lib`, `/usr/src` and some other directories with full permissions (`rwx`)

I want to prevent `devel` from:

- Accessing all other directories such as `/`, `/boot`, `/etc`, `/opt`, `/var` etc.
- Accessing certain services/deamons such as `httpd`, `sshd`, `mysqld` etc.
- Running any command (other than the basic commands above) e.g. `systemctl`.

I don't want these directories (e.g. `/`, `/etc`, `/var` etc.) to even show up to them, or at the very least disable access to them.

Is it possible to do? I have read many questions here and also many other articles, forums and blogs about ACL and Chroot Jail erc. such as [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/419160/chroot-an-user-to-more-than-one-directory-in-different-locations), [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/230709/restrict-sftp-users-to-different-directories), [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/339853/can-i-have-multiple-chroot-directories/339856), [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/359523/restrict-sftp-user-to-multiple-folders), [this](https://www.tecmint.com/restrict-sftp-user-home-directories-using-chroot/), [this](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-manage-acls-on-linux), [this](https://www.unixmen.com/implement-access-control-list-acl-centos-7/), [this](https://www.2daygeek.com/how-to-configure-access-control-lists-acls-setfacl-getfacl-linux/), [this](https://www.tecmint.com/secure-files-using-acls-in-linux/), [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/130318/restricting-directory-access-for-a-user-in-linux), [this](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-security-4/restrict-ssh-user-to-multiple-directory-4175502598/) but none of them helped me to achieve what i need to do.

Any help or any suggestions will be highly appreciated, i desperately need help.

Comment: What you're describing here isn't really practical. You will always have a `/` directory, and a lot of programs won't work without the things in `/etc` or `/dev`. And if the users have access to java/gcc/python, they can write their own replacements for many of the programs that you don't provide.

Comment: okay i can give them access to `/`. Is it possible to disable access to certain list of directories (such as `/var`, `/etc/httd`,...)?

Comment: The requirement to allow **write** access to `/usr/lib` will allow the `devel` user to gain root access. They can move aside one of the frequently-used system libraries and place their own evil version of it in its place. As soon as any root-owned process uses that library, it grants root access to `devel`, deletes itself and moves the normal library back in its place, then loads the normal library so that the root-owned process works as usual (with maybe a <0.1 second extra delay in starting). You should not allow them write access to anything that may run as root in normal system operations.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a restricted shell like rbash or rssh to restrict the capabilities of users.  (Or VirtFS/jailshell if you're willing to go that far.)  Here's an example from RH on using rbash:

https://access.redhat.com/solutions/65822